# moving rows up and down on ext grid using ext4

Tags: extjs, selection

I'm trying to enable allowing rows to be moved up and down using buttons on an ext grid using ext 4.

Here's a snippit of my code for moving a row up:

```
    var record = grid.getSelectionModel().selection.record;
    var index = grid.getStore().indexOf(record);
    var newIndex = index - 1;
    this.store.remove(selection, true);
    this.store.insert(newIndex, record);
    //selectionModel.select(record);
```

When I move it up once, it's correct the and row moves and stays highlighted. When I move it up again, then the row moves and becomes unhighlighted and deselected.

I tried selecting the record on the last line of code I commented out, but that line of code ends up highlighting the row below the moved row while keeping the moved row highlighted.

I want to be able to continually press the up button and move the selected row up without having to reselect it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a lot easier to add an extra field to the store/model that ranks the records. This way you only have to change the rank-number and then filter the store. This should keep your selection intact. If you don't want this rank-field to be synced to the proxy, set the "persist" property false on the field. That's anyway better than using private parameters on the remove method.